# How to access a property on a function?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am just starting to learn Javascript and was experimenting with functions. I wrote the following thinking that it would work. Is something like this possible or is it just *wrong*?

```
function foo() {
   console.log(this.language);
}

foo.language = "English";

foo();
```

Comment: 'this' will only exist when you have created an instance with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner - Pretty sure the OP did run it, found it doesn't work, and that's what prompted the question.

Comment: Um... yes, of course I ran it, debugged it, researched it and then eventually asked this question. `this` in javascript obviously doesn't work like other OO languages. Thanks for the downvote @Nonemoticoner.

Comment: @RobertJoseph: I don't know any OO language in which `this` refers to the function object itself… but yeah you're right, [`this` is a bit different in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: You are correct that `this` in Javascript is a bit different to other languages. Although the other languages I'm familiar with (including Java and C#) don't let you assign properties to a function and use them like that either. In JS the value of `this` depends on how a function is called, but it's almost never the function itself. I used to recommend [the MDN page about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), because it used to explain it fairly clearly, but I think the latest version is somewhat confusing. Still, it might help you.

Comment: Thank you @nnnnnn! It is funny that the first sentence in that article is, "A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, because to gain access to `this` as the current object, you'll need to instantiate the (constructor) function, which is what invoking `new` will do for you. Accessing `this` for a reference to the current instance is not only the case in Javascript though; in Java, `this` also isn't accessible from static context.

What you're looking for is something like:

```
function Foo(language) {
   this.language = language; 

}
Foo.prototype.log = function(){
   console.log(this.language); 
}    
var bar = new Foo("English"); 
bar.log();
```

Comment: [Don't create prototype methods in the constructor!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a *foo* object (an instance of *foo*) using the `new` keyword. Then set the *language* property of that instance. If *foo* has a function to output its *language* property, then you can invoke that function on your instance to see its *language*.

```
function foo() {
    this.outputLanguage = function() {
        console.log(this.language);
    }
}

var f1 = new foo();
f1.language = "English";

var f2 = new foo();
f2.language = "French";

f1.outputLanguage();
f2.outputLanguage();
```

In this example, we make 2 foo objects, and assign each a different language.

The `foo()` function is a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). We usually pass the initial values of the instance variables to it, like this:

```
function foo(language) {
    this.language = language;
    this.outputLanguage = function() {
        console.log(this.language);
    }
}

var f1 = new foo("English");
var f2 = new foo("French");

f1.outputLanguage();
f2.outputLanguage();
```

Comment: Well, this is not the case, `new` keyword was not introduced in OOP's question, anyway this answer is useful indeed

Answer (score 1):

Javascript only supports prototypal Inheritance. So to assign a property (in your case `language` is the property) to an Object (in your case `foo`) you need to use constructor. And by convention constructor are written Initcap.

```
function Foo(lang){
 this.language = lang;
}

Foo.prototype.getLanguage = function(){
  return this.language;
}

var lang1 = new Foo('english');
var lang2 = new Foo('bengali');

console.log(lang1.getLanguage()); // english
console.log(lang2.getLanguage()); // bengali
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is available on instance variables, in your case it's *named* function

```
function foo() {
   console.log(foo.language); //instead of this, use function property
}

foo.language = "English";

foo();
```

If you want to dive more, checkout my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35379449/2308005) for the same topic

Comment: *"it's anonymous named"* - Um...if it has a name it isn't anonymous.

Comment: @nnnnnn oh, it's named, thanks for help, i've updated

Comment: Thanks @MedetTleukabiluly. This works. Why did it get a downvote?

Comment: @RobertJoseph i don't know, maybe someone hates quick answers

Comment: @RobertJoseph checkout also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35379449/2308005)